# Can Endpoints JS Client utilize GAE User Api Authorization (js/python)

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using the python version of GAE. For most pages I authenticate the user server side with google.appengine.api.users

```
 user = users.get_current_user()
 if user:
     # Great user logged in proceed
     ... 
 else:
     # Oops user not logged in and/or App not yet authorized
     # Present user with login dialogue then redirect here
```

So the user logs in and authenticates my app. Sometime later the user encounters a page with some java script functionality that uses google endpoints. The user is still logged into the page but it seems like I am forced to present another login dialogue before the endpoints api server side recognizes the User

Relevant JS Code:

```
iaw.signin = function(mode, callback) {

    // Hoping setting mode to true here (no authorization prompt)
    // magically figures out user already logged into browser and
    // picks up relevant token/headers to feed to endpoints and
    // verifies user authorized and logged in
    // note: callback = iaw.userAuthed
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: iaw.CLIENT_ID,
        scope: iaw.SCOPES, immediate: mode},
        callback);
};

iaw.userAuthed = function() {

    var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
        if (!resp.code) {
            console.log('Succefully logged in');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Not successfully logged in');
        }
    });
};
```

Version of code above always prints "Not successfully logged in". If I follow the google example and call gapi.auth.authorize({ immediate: false}) it will present the user with another login dialogue and then everything works.

Is what I am trying to do possible? It just seems unfortunate in some cases to ask my user to login (authorize backend server code) and then immediately ask them to login again (authorize my javascript client code).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour]. Right now your question is on the edge of being off topic

Comment: I reworded my question hopefully it is more clear and on topic.